# How to get accesstoken from Xamarin Auth - Google

Tags: android, xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.android, xamarin.auth

I am trying to get auth token from 0auth2 in the android app. The issue is once i sign, in the app is restaring because of the redirect url but I am not getting any auth token from the intent once the app is restarted.

**code**

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(ClientID, ClientSecret, Scope, new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                new Uri("com.app.abcd:/oauthredirect"), new Uri("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"), null, true);
 authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
                authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;
                var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
                presenter.Login(authenticator);

 private async void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
            if (authenticator != null)
            {
                authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
                authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
            }

            IsAuthorized = e.IsAuthenticated;
            //User user = null;
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {}
}
```

**Android**

```
[Activity(Label = "ABCD", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
        //DataScheme = "abcd",
         DataSchemes = new[] { "com.app.abcd" },
               DataPath = "/oauthredirect",
              AutoVerify = true)]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                DependencyService.Register<ChromeCustomTabsBrowser>();
                CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

                TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
                ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
                LoadApplication(new App());
        }
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            //HandleNotificationIntent(intent);
        }

        protected override void OnRestart()
        {
            var intent = this.Intent;
            base.OnRestart();
        }
}
```

When i run this code and `presenter.Login(authenticator);`is called i can see the google authenticates the user and `OnNewIntent` is called and app is restarted and `OnAuthCompleted` is never called and I am not able to get the access token.

Is this the right way to get accesstoken form 0auth2 or am i missing something? can anyone help me with this.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/someone1984-Xamarin.Auth-sample/AuthExample/AuthExample

This sample is really helpful. It helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please share your solution here, and mark your reply as answer,it is very helpful for the person that encountering the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Check out the example [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/someone1984-Xamarin.Auth-sample/AuthExample).

**Common Code**:

```
 private void Authenticate()
        {
            var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(ClientID, ClientSecret, Scope, new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                            new Uri("com.app.abcd:/oauthredirect"), new Uri("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"), null, true);
            authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
            authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;
            var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
            presenter.Login(authenticator);
        }

        private async void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
            if (authenticator != null)
            {
                authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
                authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
            }

            IsAuthorized = e.IsAuthenticated;
            //User user = null;
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var access_token = e.Account.Properties["access_token"];
                var expires_in = e.Account.Properties["expires_in"];
                var refresh_token = e.Account.Properties["refresh_token"];
            }
        }
```

**ANDROID**:
Create a new activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor", NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [IntentFilter(
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "com.app.abcd" },
        DataPath = "/oauthredirect")]
    public class ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Android.Net.Uri uri_android = Intent.Data;

            // Convert Android.Net.Url to Uri
            var uri = new Uri(uri_android.ToString());
            // Close browser 
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            //intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            StartActivity(intent);

            // Load redirectUrl page
            // if the code below isn't accessible, pass `authenticator`
            // created in the common code here which has `OnPageLoading(uri);` method 
           OAuthAuthenticatorHelper.AuthenticationState.OnPageLoading(uri);
            this.Finish();
        }
    }
```

**iOS**

Add couple of lines in `OpenUrl` to handle the url redirect

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
        {
            // Convert iOS NSUrl to C#/netxf/BCL System.Uri - common API
            Uri uri_netfx = new Uri(url.AbsoluteString);

            // load redirect_url Page for parsing
            OAuthAuthenticatorHelper.AuthenticationState.OnPageLoading(uri_netfx);

            return true;
        }
```

In info.plist add the urlscheme of the package name:

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
              <string>com.app.abcd</string>
            </array>
```